# Employer not sending corrected W-2. What can I do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, form-w-2

For USA tax year 2022: I got my W-2 via ADP in February 2023. It had a mistake and I requested a corrected version (W-2C) in March 2023. Tax filing was due in April 2023 so I filed an extension (federal + state). Payroll department at my company told me that it will take 6-8 weeks for corrected W-2. Since then, they keep pushing the dates and it has been 4.5 months.

It is August now and they still have not sent me the corrected W-2. Tax extension deadline is near (October 2023).

**Questions:** What are my options if they don't send me the corrected W-2? What happens if I don't file my taxes by October 2023 for any reason?

Comment: After warning my employer that I will lodge a complaint to IRS, I finally got my W-2 updated with correct info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What are my options if they don't send me the corrected W-2? What
> happens if I don't file my taxes by October 2023 for any reason?

The IRS has guidance: [W-2 - Additional, Incorrect, Lost, Non-Receipt, Omitted](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted)

> **Question**
>
> I received an incorrect Form W-2. My former employer won’t
> issue me a corrected Form W-2. What should I do?
>
> **Answer**
>
> If by the end of February, your Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement has
> not been corrected by your employer after you attempted to have your
> employer or payer issue a corrected form, you can request that an IRS
> representative initiate a Form W-2 complaint. Call the IRS toll free
> at 800-829-1040 or make an appointment to visit an IRS Taxpayer
> Assistance Center (TAC).
>
> - The IRS will send your employer a letter requesting that they furnish you a corrected Form W-2 within ten days.
> - The IRS will send you a letter with instructions and Form 4852, Substitute for Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement, or Form 1099-R,
>   Distributions from Pensions, Annuities, Retirement or Profit-Sharing
>   Plans, IRAs, Insurance Contracts, etc. You can use the Form 4852 in
>   the event that your employer doesn't provide you with the corrected
>   Form W-2 in time to file your tax return.
>
> Depending on the time of year, the IRS may have federal wage
> information in the form of a wage transcript. See Topic 159 for more
> information on how to get a transcript of W-2 information.

It may be possible to use the information on your last paycheck. But it does matter what information is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the IRS to move any faster, I've been trying to get them to fix something for over a year.  The last call they told me to be patient because they were short staffed.

Comment: @rtaft I think one of the pieces of the debt ceiling deal was rescinding the increased IRS budget that was made in the Inflation Reduction Act.